# How to create graph in an HTML file using the jOrgChart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, charts

Is it possible to draw a graph in an HTML file using the jOrgChart jQuery plugin, as in the example below?

If that's not possible then what are other options are available for drawing such chart, without using Drupal?

[image: Example graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this question is about the [jOrgChart jQuery plugin](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart), and assuming that [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) is an option to consider, then for sure it's worth considering the [jOrgChart sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/natchetoi/2063775) ... at least that's where I'll start from if some day I want to start using jOrgChart in Drupal.

For other Drupal based alternatives for charting, checkout the [Comparison of charting](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) modules I created (note to myself: add this jOrgChart plugin and sandbox project to that comparison).

Curious to hear to what extend this attempt is an answer to this charting question ...

PS: Checkout [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640431/pierre-vriens) for more details about my charting background, etc.

Comment: Its in HTML, JavaScript. not drupal

Answer (score 0):

1. Very easy to use given a nested unordered list element.
2. Drag-and-drop functionality allows reordering of the tree and
   underlying  structure.
3. Showing/hiding a particular branch of the tree by clicking on the
   respective node.
4. Nodes can contain any amount of HTML except

   and . Easy to
   style.

   You can specify that sub-trees should start collapsed, which is
   useful for very large trees
   for html 
   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html